# Interactively entering enable mode with Java and expectit

Tags: java, expect, expectit

I am doing some maintenance on some network devices and I've been using Expectit to navigate through the menus.  However, I've only been successful when the devices provide prompts I expect.  For example, some devices are already in enable mode when I log in, but some are not.

I would like to do the equivalent of:

```
Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
        .withOutput(channel.getOutputStream())
        .withInputs(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getExtInputStream())
        .withEchoOutput(wholeBuffer)
        .withEchoInput(wholeBuffer)
        .withExceptionOnFailure()
        .build();

channel.connect();
if (expect.expect(contains(">")) {
    expect.sendLine("enable");
    expect.expect("assword:");
    expect.sendLine(password);
}
expect.expect(contains("#"));
```

but I know this isn't right and it doesn't work.  Some assistance on implementing a reaction to a certain prompt and another reaction to other prompts would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ExpectIt#interact](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt/blob/master/expect-java8/src/main/java/net/sf/expectit/java8/Java8Example.java) but it seems to be broken in version 0.8.0, so try out the latest version 0.8.1.

Without `interact` you can use the `anyOf` matcher and have the logic based on the condition of individual results. This is basically how `interact` works. Here is an example:

```
MultiResult multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(contains(">"), contains("#")));
if (multiResult.getResults().get(0).isSuccessful()) {
    expect.sendLine("enable");
    expect.expect(contains("assword:"));
    expect.sendLine(password);
} else if (multiResult.getResults().get(1).isSuccessful()) {
   expect.expect(contains("#"));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help here.  The anyOf does exactly what I need.